# How can I combine two blocks to simplify my code?

Tags: ruby

Hi I am a student learning Ruby. I am using the [quick start guide at ruby-lang.org](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ko/documentation/quickstart/3/), which has some examples of Ruby basics.

I studied the `MegaGreeter` class, and I am trying to figure out how to `puts` two arguments (`name` and `age`) in the same `each` block in order to simplify my code.

I think there would be another way. (Using regular loops instead of `each`.)

1. Calculate the array's size.
2. Use a loop like in C.

But I want to use the `each` loop. Below is my code:

```
class MegaGreeter
    attr_accessor :name
    attr_accessor :age

    #Creat the object
    def initialize(name=nil, age=0)
        @name = name
        @age = age
        @tmp = Array.new()
        @i = 0
    end

    #Say hi to everybody
    def say_hi
        if @name.nil?
            puts "please give me the input !!"
        elsif @name.respond_to?("each")
            #list responding
            @name.each do |name|
                @tmp[@i] = "hi ~! #{name}"
                @i += 1
            end
            @i=0
            @age.each do |age|
                @tmp[@i] += " and you are #{age} years old"
                puts @tmp[@i]
                @i += 1
            end
        else
            puts "give me array ~"
        end
    end
end

a = MegaGreeter.new()
a.name = ["juno","yoonhe"]
a.age = [1,2]
a.say_hi
```

Comment: In by `puts more than 2 arguments`, what do you mean by arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Array` method [`zip`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip) to first combine your two arrays. It groups the elements by their position in the array, so the first element of the `@name` array will be grouped with the first element of the `@age` array and so on.

```
@name = ['Foo', 'Bar']
@age = [23, 41]

name_and_age = @name.zip(@age)
# [['Foo', 23], ['Bar' 41]]
```

Now the names and ages are grouped together, and you can iterate over them using `each`.

```
name_and_age.each do |name, age|
  puts name, age
end
# Foo 23
# Bar 41
```

Putting it back into your original code:

```
class MegaGreeter
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  #Creat the object
  def initialize(name = nil, age = 0)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end

  #Say hi to everybody
  def say_hi
    if @name.nil?
      puts "please give me the input !!"
    elsif @name.respond_to?("each")
      #list responding
      @name.zip(@age).each do |name, age|
        puts "hi ~! #{name} and you are #{age} years old"
      end
    else
      puts "give me array ~"
    end
  end
end
```